Making the drawed text on the imageview selectable
I am turning pdf pages into bitmaps and displaying them on recyclerview and ı draw the detected text on the bitmap with drawtext(); and ı want to be able to select these texts on the recycleviews imageviews
ı am drawing the detected text on the bitmap when ı touch the screen and the text being drawned on the bitmap and it cant be selectable because the text becomes a part of the bitmap what is the best way to make the text selectable

very interesting question, but personally I doubt it's possible... text selection is a system feature, which is probably intended to work with TextView only, so maybe better aproach is to split "drawing" to one View and place above it TextView for text placing and selection purposes

Placing Textview seems like best aproach but ı couldnt figure out how to place textviews on the recycleview dynamicly is there example about this you could recommend

well, that very depends on your implementation, would suggest to place your code in separate question. maybe there is a way and this question will get an answer some day :) (maybe before you decide to re-write your whole solution for TextView placing and selection possibility)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
